# In Google Sheets how can I write a script to move a drawing to a specific location on the sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a Google sheet with a drawing i.e. shape. What script would move the shape to a designated location on the sheet?

Here is a link to an example where I'd like to click on the blue rectangle and have the script move the green rectangle to cover cell A1.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eFCwDiY90ZM5SIMa6C0rSdhG_oC-SWgsk8vAvjIR34s

This is my first script in Google and I can't find a way to select the drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to move the drawing, which is the green rectangle, to the cell "A1" when the blue rectangle is clicked.

For this, how about this answer?

### Usage:

#### 1. Set function name.

At first, please set the function name of `myFunction` to "the blue rectangle". By this, when the blue rectangle is clicked, `myFunction` is run.

#### 2. Sample script.

```
function myFunction() {
  // 1. Retrieve sheet.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  // 2. Retrieve "the green rectangle".
  const drawing = sheet.getDrawings().filter(e => e.getOnAction() != "myFunction")[0];

  // 3. Move "the green rectangle".
  drawing.setPosition(1, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

- In this case, the blue rectangle has the function name of `myFunction`. So using this, the green rectangle is retrieved.
- In order to run this script, please click the blue rectangle that `myFunction` was set. By this, the green rectangle is moved to the cell "A1".

### Note:

- This is a sample script. So please modify this for your actual situation.

### Reference:

- [Class Drawing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/drawing)

Comment: This works great and I'll happy accept the answer. If it isn't too much trouble can I update the question and add another requirement that I can't figure out? What if there is also a purple triangle and I want to move it to D10?

Comment: @Hawsidog Thank you for replying. About your additional question, in the current stage, unfortunately, each drawing cannot be distinguished by the object color and the identifier. So in your question, I used whether the function is set as the identifier. From this situation, in order to achieve your new question, for example, how about putting each drawing to the predetermined cells and using each drawing the anchor cell as the identifier?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did in my sheet and it worked; there may be a better way but at least this is easy to implement:

```
function placeDrawing(row, col, offsetY, offsetX){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("sheetName");
  var drawings = ss.getDrawings(); //This returns an array of all drawings in the sheet 
  drawings[0].setPosition(row, col, offsetY,  offsetX);//for each drawing set the wanted position
}
```

Of course, you will need some testing to guess the exact index (mine were 0 and 1 of 8 drawings), or you can do a for to iterate them.